# Problem with output, the if statement is being executed when it should not

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class CE_Sandwich {

```
public static final double SAND_COST = 3.50;
public static final double SALAD_COST = 4.50;
public static final double PLATTER_COST = 6.50;

public static final double SAND_COST_X3 = 2.75;
public static final double SALAD_COST_X3 = 3.75;
public static final double PLATTER_COST_X3 = 5.75;

public static final int SANDWICH = 1;
public static final int SALADS = 2;
public static final int PLATTER = 3;



public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("\t Welcome to HCC's Sandwich Shop");
    System.out.println("What would you like? Type in the number lsited before each item to order.");
    System.out.println("(1)SANDWICHES - $3.50 for 1 or $2.75 when you buy 3 or more");
    System.out.println("(2)SALADS - $4.50 for 1 or $3.75 when you buy 3 or more");
    System.out.println("(3)PLATTERS - $6.50 for 1 or $5.75 when you buy 3 or more");
    int count;
    int input2;
    int input = scan.nextInt();
    
    do {
        if (input == SANDWICH) {
            
                do {
                    System.out.println("How many sandwiches?");
                    count = scan.nextInt();
                    
                    if (count<1) {                          
                        System.out.println("ERROR - VALUE CANNOT BE LESS THAN 1. PLEASE RE-ENTER");
                            }
                    
                    if (count<=2) {
                            double cost = count * SAND_COST;
                        System.out.printf("TOTAL COST OF ORDER IS $%.2f%n", cost);
                            }
                    if (count>=3) {
                        
                        double cost = count * SAND_COST_X3;
                        System.out.printf("TOTAL COST OF ORDER IS $%.2f%n", cost);
                        
                    }
                        
                        
                    }while (count <1);
                    
                }
        if (input == SALADS) {
            
            do {
                System.out.println("How many salads?");
                count = scan.nextInt();
                
                if (count<1) {                          
                    System.out.println("ERROR - VALUE CANNOT BE LESS THAN 1. PLEASE RE-ENTER");
                        }
                
                if (count<=2) {
                        double cost = count * SALAD_COST;
                    System.out.printf("TOTAL COST OF ORDER IS $%.2f%n", cost);
                        }
                if (count>=3) {
                    
                    double cost = count * SALAD_COST_X3;
                    System.out.printf("TOTAL COST OF ORDER IS $%.2f%n", cost);
                    
                }
                    
                    
                }while (count <1);
                
            }
        
        if (input == PLATTER) {
            
            do {
                System.out.println("How many platters?");
                count = scan.nextInt();
                
                if (count<1) {                          
                    System.out.println("ERROR - VALUE CANNOT BE LESS THAN 1. PLEASE RE-ENTER");
                        }
                
                if (count<=2) {
                        double cost = count * PLATTER_COST;
                    System.out.printf("TOTAL COST OF ORDER IS $%.2f%n", cost);
                        }
                if (count>=3) {
                    
                    double cost = count * PLATTER_COST_X3;
                    System.out.printf("TOTAL COST OF ORDER IS $%.2f%n", cost);
                    
                }
                    
                    
                }while (count <1);
                
                }   
            
            System.out.println("Do you wish to re order? Press 1 for Yes or 0 for No");
                input2 = scan.nextInt();
                
            }while (input2 == 1);
        
        if (input2 == 0) {
            
            System.out.println("GOODBYE :)");
        }
        }
    
    
}
```

When I run the program, the output whenever I input a value lower than 1 for count, is a error message, but it also multiplies it by the cost. What am i doing wrong???? Any help is appreciated. I have linked the output and basically when an error message is displayed it shouldnt do the calculations yet is does.
[THE OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJIKl.jpg)

Comment: You have entered -3, so this value is less than 1 and less&equals 2. So first IF and second IF are handled. Try to change second IF to `if (count==2)`

Comment: You need to find a way to perhaps exit the loop or restart the loop to do what you want. You could throw an exception or use the "continue" statement.

Answer (score 2):

If a value is less than 1, it's also less than or equal to 2.

So in something like this:

```
     if (count < 1)
          xxxx;
     if (count <= 2)
          yyyy;
```

for values 0 or less, both xxxx and yyyy will be executed.  You probably mean

```
     if (count < 1)
          xxxx;
     else if (count <= 2)
          yyyy;
```

I hope that with that hint you can figure out the changes you need to make.